# File conflict whem installing with CMake

Tags: cmake, installation

My project produces several executables that I want to install. My install directory is roughly composed of a `bin` folder for the executables and a `lib` folder to install the dependencies (`.so` files) of those executables.

Each executables are installed as it's own custom target by calling the `cmake_install.cmake` script.

```
add_custom_target(target_install
  ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
  -D "BUILD_TYPE=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}"
  -D "CMAKE_INSTALL_COMPONENT=${target_component}"
  -P "cmake_install.cmake"
  COMMENT "Installing target..."
)
```

Those executables have mostly similar dependencies ( boost, ...), and when CMake try to install an already installed dependency, it usually just skip it.
The problem is when Cmake multitask the installation of those executables. It then tries to simultaneously install their dependencies which often lead to trying to copy twice the same file at the same moment. That lead to an error and fail the installation.

```
    -- Installing: lib/libboost_chrono.so
    -- Installing: lib/libboost_chrono.so
    -- Installing: lib/libboost_chrono.so.1.66.0
    -- Installing: lib/libboost_chrono.so.1.66.0
    -- Installing: lib/libboost_regex.so
    -- Installing: lib/libboost_regex.so
    -- Installing: lib/libboost_regex.so.1.66.0
    CMake Error at src/cmake_install.cmake:88 (file):
      file INSTALL cannot duplicate symlink "/usr/lib/libboost_regex.so" at
      "lib/libboost_regex.so".
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      cmake_install.cmake:42 (include)
      "/home/docker/wkp/install/codebase/develop/ServeurIti/creb/lib/libboost_regex.so".
    Call Stack (most recent call first):
      cmake_install.cmake:42 (include)
```

How can I keep CMake from trying to install several target at the same time ?

Comment: Why did not edit your [prevous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55222320/conflict-when-installing-libs-with-cmake) instead of deleting it and ansking the new one about the same topic? The previous question had no downvotes and answers, so nothing prevented it to be edited even with a big changes.

Comment: "How can I keep CMake from trying to install several target at the same time?" - Except "do not use multitask" it is hard to suggest anything. You have a clear data race when accessing installed files, and CMake unlikely has a cross-process mechanism for syncrhonize those accesses. BTW, normally components emit `install()` commands instead of creating *custom installation target*.

Comment: I found my previous question poorly asked and as I do not exactly know the way stackoverflow display  all the questions, I feared just modifying the content would have gone unnoticed.

Comment: I do not know how to "not use multitask". That seems to be the standard way of doing thing in Cmake/Makefile and I do not know how to disable it. Also the standard `install()` did not work for me, as my project is in fact multiple projects which should be able to be build and installed separatly due to legacy reason.

Comment: It seems there is ways to run a Makefile in serial (.NOTPARALLEL) but i can't find how to use that in CMake

Comment: I do not know how to "not use multitask". - Just do not pass `-jN` option for `make`. Or pass `-j1` option, which enforces to use the only thread. BTW, if you want to just install several projects, no needs to use CMake - just write a shell script which installs them.

Comment: I'd rather use well Cmake than create multiples scripts to do what Cmake is supposed to do. We already have a good number of scripts in the project and are not willing to add more if we can help it. Plus I'm not really the one that can make that kind of decision...